# Adding Custom print action in bulk action for orders in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, printing, hook

```
<?php
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'my_custom_bulk_action' );
function my_custom_bulk_action( $actions ) {
    $actions['print_setected'] = __( 'Print', 'my-textdomain' );
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'print_selected_orders', 10 , 3 );
function print_selected_orders($doaction,$order_ids) {
    if($doaction == 'print_selected'){
        $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'    => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$orders_ids = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $orders_ids as $order_id ) {
    //$order_id = $order->ID;
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_note = $order->get_customer_note();
        $order_no = $order->get_order_number();
        $order_total = $order->get_total();
        
        echo 'Order ID: ' . $order_id . '<br>';
        echo 'Order Note: ' . $order_note . '<br>';
        echo 'Order Total:'.$order_total;
    }   
    }
}
?>
```

I was trying to add bulk action to print all orders in bulk from Woo-Commerce orders page. I am using the above code but nothing happens it just redirects to 'edit PHP' page and the includes all the ids of the orders that are selected to print but the page is blank nothing displays